# Текст в JTable в Java

Tags: jtable, jscrollpane, java, swing

Загружаю данные из Интернета в DefaultTableModel, создаю JTable с DefaultTableModel и дальше JTable помещаю в JScrollPane. Текст во второй колонке длиннее ее ширины. Как добавить горизонтальную прокрутку?

Картинка: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GJe7me67cnSmFKbkJuTXBhNGc/view?usp=sharing

```
JScrollPane mainScrollPane =new JScrollPane(recordsTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

не помогает.

Comment: И не поможет. Суммарная ширина колонок не превышает ширины таблицы. Вам нужно установить ширину колонки равной ширине текста колонки и только потом (AS NEEDED) отобразится горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

Comment: "Вам нужно установить ширину колонки равной ширине текста" как сделать?

Comment: @grodt.
У меня это реализовано следующим методом. col - номер вашего столбца.

    public static void pack(JTable table, int col) {
        int width = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
        }
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setMinWidth(width);
    }

Брал откуда-то с stackoverflow.com